# Differentiating between # and ## comments in Python for Sublime Text 2

Tags: python, comments, sublimetext2

Using Ctrl + / on Sublime Text transforms

```
This is a comment.
```

to

```
# This is a comment.
```

However, I also want to have comments prefixed by ##, and I want them to have:
1. a different color
2. a different keyboard shortcut

from those prefixed by #. Something like:

```
# Sample function
def fxn(a):
    ## oops wrong line
    a + 1
```

I've tried tinkering with Comments.tmPreferences, but `TM_COMMENT_START_2` and the `TM_COMMENT_END_2` require that the code be placed in between these characters. I also tried setting `TM_COMMENT_START_2` to `##` and `TM_COMMENT_END_2` to a single space, but it also doesn't work.

How do I do this in Sublime Text 2? Thank you.